# Error en la sentencia de sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Buenas tengo un ejercicio de sql uso sqldevelop y yo veo mi sentencia igual a la del profesor pero a mi me da error y a el no 
el ejercicios es este odificar el programa PL/SQL que permita aumentar en un 10% el salario de un empleado cuyo número se introduce por teclado.

```
DECLARE
    cursor curs(argumento number) IS
    SELECT * FROM temple where numen=argumento for update of salar;
    registro curs%rowtype;
 begin
    OPEN curs(&Numero_empleado);
    FETCH curs INTO registro;
    UPDATE temple SET salar=salar*1.1 WHERE CURRENT OF curs;
    CLOSE curs;
END;
```

este es el link del scrip por si lo quereis probar https://www.dropbox.com/s/2v4jgswdp4ux8bd/CreaTrasCor.SQL?dl=0

```
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 32:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NUMEN": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:
PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'CURS' is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 4, column 14:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 18:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 7, column 2:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Comment: Pues por el error lo que parece es que `numen` no te lo está reconociendo como un campo válido.

Comment: no entiendo porque mira este es el codigo del profesor    
cursor cur1(argu1 number) IS
 SELECT * FROM temple WHERE numem=argu1 FOR UPDATE OF salar;
     registro cur1%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
 OPEN cur1(&Numero_empleado);
 FETCH cur1 INTO registro;
 UPDATE temple SET salar=salar*1.1 WHERE CURRENT OF cur1;
-- COMMIT;
 CLOSE cur1;
END;

Comment: @carlosdiaz El primer WHERE, en tu codigo pone `numen`, en el del profesor pone `numem`, la última letra es `m`.

Comment: mierda vale gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta línea:

```
SELECT * FROM temple where numen=argumento for update of salar;
```

Tú pones `where numen=argumento`, y el profesor tiene el equivalente a `where numem=argument`.

`numen` -> **`numem`**.